# If $f^{(n)}(x)$ continous at a certain point ,then $f^{(n)}(x)$ continous over a neighbourhood of the point?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $n$ is a non-negative integer,$f$ diferentiable $n$ times in a neighbourhood of $x_{0}\in \mathbf{R},(x_{0}-\delta ,x_{0}+\delta ),$ and  $f^{(n)}(x),$ the $n$th derivative of $f$ ,is continuous at $x=x_{0}.$
Is there a real number $\delta_{1},0<\delta_{1}<\delta,$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is continous over $(x_{0}-\delta_{1} ,x_{0}+\delta_{1} )?$

When $n=0,$it is  not difficulty to find  a counterexample:

Let
$$x_{0}=0,\qquad f(x)=\begin{cases}
 x^{2}& \text{if}\quad x \text { is a irratioanl number},\\ 
 0& \text{if}\quad x \text { is a rational number}. 
\end{cases} \quad $$

Go a step further，I need to find some counterexamples for higher orders,
but I'm stumped for that .Can anyone give me any hints on how to start it? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. The answer to the title question is "no", as may be deduced by (repeatedly) integrating the function constructed in the answer to [If $f'$ is differentiable at $a$ then $f'$ is continuous at $(a - \delta,a + \delta)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617505).

2. Your proposed function is arguably not a counterexample, since $f'$ exists at only one point.

3. Incidentally, the term "fixed point" in the title has a technical meaning ("an $x$ such that $f(x) = x$"); since that appears not to be your intent, you might consider rewording the title. :)

Comment: @Andrew D.Hwang:Thanks for your very helpful links . Yes,my example is not a counterexample,if you consider $f^{(1)}$ .But  if you only consider $f^{(0)}$(i.e.$f$),It's a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: Given $a<b,$ there exists a differentiable $g$ on $[a,b]$ such that $g'$ is bounded on $[a,b],$ $g'(a) = g'(b)=0,$ and $g'$ is discontinuous at $(a+b)/2.$ For example, on $[-1,1]$ we could take

$$g(x) = (x+1)^2(x-1)^2 x^2 \sin(1/x)$$

(with $g(0) =0$ of course). Now let $a_1 > a_2 > \cdots \to 0.$ For each $n$ we can choose a $g_n$ on $[a_{n+1},a_n]$ that does the above on this interval. Paste these $g_n$'s together and perhaps you'll see how to finish up for an example in the case $n=1.$ (This should yield examples for $n> 1$ as well.)